# Api não retorna JSON corretamente

Tags: python, json, api

Estou tentando fazer uma requisição de uma lista que deveria conter os indices 'asks' e 'bids' porém só consigo 'bids', não sei se existe um limite para o tamanho da requisição em python, também não consigo tratar esta resposta com JSON, segue o código:

```
import requests as req
from binance.client import Client

class Binance():


def __init__(self, coin, base, publicApiKey, privateApiKey):
    self.coin = coin.upper()
    self.base = base.upper()
    self.pair = coin + base
    self.publicKey = publicApiKey
    self.privateKey = privateApiKey
    self.client = Client(self.publicKey, self.privateKey)
def getPair(self): return self.pair

def getName(self): return 'Binance'
def getTest(self): return self. client.get_order_book(symbol=self.coin+self.base)
def getPairBid(self):
    bid = self.client.get_order_book(symbol=self.coin + self.base)['bids']
    return bid
def getPairAsk(self):
    ask = self.client.get_order_book(symbol=self.coin + self.base)['ask']
    return ask

def sellBuy(self):
    bid = req.get('http://api.coinbene.com/v1/market/ticker?symbol=' + self.coin + self.base).json()['ticker'][0]['bid']
    ask = req.get('http://api.coinbene.com/v1/market/ticker?symbol=' + self.coin + self.base).json()['ticker'][0]['ask']
    return '::: Binance :::\n' + 'Buy: ' + str(bid) + '\n' + 'Sell: ' + str(ask) + '\n' + '/---------------------/'



print(Binance('eth', 'btc','NjD7K42nXFoRG2ptb1ify7YMlWjEH6E7JnhMDLhuxLsOzZp0SFQZy9bqLMAwI7va'
    ,'ZrNB0jJzjEhYVrBYS3FjjUeCucAJT2TBt0mVfLJJ5Q7PI8a48fxcVXTDO5sBpxDH').getTest())
```

link da API: https://github.com/sammchardy/python-binance

Comment: ja testou no postman?

Comment: Problema é que tu tá colocando `ask` e não `asks`, não?

Comment: Qual o problema com o JSON? Aqui eu consegui processar normalmente.

Comment: @Tmilitino cara, era isso, nem prestei atenção, obrigado !